# What is the difference between $A[j_{i+1}]$ And $A[j_{i}+1]$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the difference between

$A[j_{i+1}]$
And
$A[j_{i}+1]$
?

If we have an array A[1,2,3,4] and i=2 then is
$A[j_{3+1}]$ the same as $A[j_{2}+1]$ ? Would both give 4 as the answer?

Comment: What if your array was $A[3,6,1,9]$?

Comment: The functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^3+x^2$ give the same values at $x=0$.  Do you conclude from that that they must be the same function?

Comment: @DanPollard with the array $A[3,6,1,9] $, if i = 2 then  $A[j_{i+1}] $ would be $A[i_3]$ which would be 1 and $A[j_{i} + 1]$ would be $A[j_{2}+ 1] $ which I am not sure if it would be $A[i_3]$. If it is was then it would be 1 too. It goes back to my question if $A[j_{i+1}]$ is the same as $A[j_{i}+1]$  I'm not sure im following what you are trying to say. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are some things to unpack here - mostly just notation.

You have an Array A=[1,2,3,4]. You can address the elements of this array as A[n], where n starts at 1 (or 0 if you prefer) and goes for the length of your array. If you start at 1, you would have A[1] = 1, A[2] = 2, A[3] = 3 and A[4] = 4.
If your array contained different numbers say B=[1,3,7,1] you would have B[1] = 1, B[2] = 3, B[3] = 9 and B[4]=1.

You also asked about $A[j_i + 1]$ and $A[j_{i+1}]$. Here we have a second enumeration-structure, namely the $j_i$. Those are commonly any enumeration of indices. For example you could have $j_1 = 3, j_2=2, j_3=4, j_4=4$. They need not follow any pattern, they are mostly a convenient way to keep track of variables. And here you can see the difference between $j_i + 1$ and $j_{i+1}$. We have
$$j_1 + 1 = 3 + 1 =4,$$
since I defined $j_1$ to be $3$. However
$$j_{1+1}=j_2=2 \neq 4,$$
also because I defined $j_2=2$.

So to answer your question, no, $j_i +1$ and $j_{i+1}$ are generally not the same. And as a consequence, also $A[j_i +1]$ and $A[j_{i+1}]$ are generally not the same. But to answer wether they are the same in a specific case, you would need to specify what your $j_i$ are.

Comment: Great! I understand it now. Thank you